# Strange behavior of a SEDE query for Stack Overflow with Unicode characters

Tags: support, data-explorer

When I try to find users from China and use `Location LIKE '%中国%'`, it shows some strange result, whose location is `???`.

Why?

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/908165

And SQL:

```
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Reputation DESC) AS [#], 
    Id AS Link, 
    DisplayName,
    location,
    Reputation
FROM
    Users
WHERE
     Location LIKE '%中国%'
ORDER BY
    Reputation DESC;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/49734390/1 ? (it happens that OP edit the *question* to add the `N` in revision 2, which changes the question and invalidates some existing comments)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Using a Unicode string `N'%中国%'` instead of `'%中国%'` gives you the desired results:

```
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Reputation DESC) AS [#], 
    Id AS Link, 
    DisplayName,
    location,
    Reputation
FROM
    Users
WHERE
     Location LIKE N'%中国%'
ORDER BY
    Reputation DESC;
```

See https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/155859/why-do-we-need-to-put-n-before-strings-in-microsoft-sql-server for an explanation.